# How to achieve react portal functionality in react 15?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react 15 in my current project, however I want to show the overlay on screen on my dropdown opens. In react 16 we can use React portal to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.
how to achieve same in react 15 version?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create parent component that manages the child component you originally have in addition to another component you create to hold the overlay. The basic idea is the following:

```
ParentComponent -> ChildCallingComponent
                -> ChildOverlayComponent
```

Then in your ChildCallingComponent when you want to show the overlay, use a prop callback to request ParentComponent change the data it sends to ChildOverlayComponent, such as showOverlay={true}.

Note that depending on how large your application is and at which level in the DOM tree you wish to insert the overlay, there may be many callbacks up parent components. A better solution is using a state management library like Redux, then you can make a state change directly from ChildCallingComponent to ChildOverlayComponent in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

There are third-party React 15 ports for some React 16+ features, including portals.

[`react-portal`](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal) provides common API for portals in React 15 and 16+. It uses [own portal implementation](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal/blob/master/src/LegacyPortal.js) if portals (`React.createPortal`) are not supported in current React version.